# Why does the contextMenu modifier does not work when inside of a modal sheet

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code. The goal is to have a VStack of buttons with navigation items that can be expanded into a context menu. I have the following code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented: Bool = true
    var contextMenuButton: some View {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")!).resizable()
            .contextMenu {
                Button {} label: {
                    Label("Download", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.down ")
                }
            }.frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                contextMenuButton
            }.navigationTitle("The title")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            VStack {
                Text("I have some deets")
            }.presentationDetents([.large, .medium, .height(10)])
                .interactiveDismissDisabled()
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as the .sheet is there, the navigation item no longer works. Is there a reason for this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow user interaction in views behind a sheet in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72693785/allow-user-interaction-in-views-behind-a-sheet-in-swiftui)